# Get the Top level Site URL without SpContext.Current.Site.URL

Tags: site-collection

I am trying to get the top lever site URL in my timer job. Right now, I am using SPContext.Current.Site.Url which is giving an error. Please let me know how do I get the top level Site URL being in a ListItem. I have the code as follows

```
if (item[new Guid(Fields.ThumbnailFieldId)] != null)
        {
            SPFieldUrlValue thumbnail = new SPFieldUrlValue(item[new Guid(Fields.ThumbnailFieldId)].ToString());                
            string tempURL = thumbnail.Url.Replace("http://intranet.swlstg-test.nhs.uk", SPContext.Current.Site.Url.ToString());                    
            this.ThumbnailUrl = tempURL.ToString();              
        }
```

I have my newsitem is in the following I am trying to change the `thumbnail.Url` to SPContext.current.site.url alternative.

```
public NewsItemForTimerJob(SPListItem item)
    {
        // Get item details
        this.Title = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title].ToString();
        this.StartDate = (DateTime)item[new Guid(Fields.StartDateFieldId)];
        this.EndDate = (DateTime)item[new Guid(Fields.EndDateFieldId)];
        this.ContentType = item.ContentType.Name;
        this.Headline = item[new Guid(Fields.HeadlineFieldId)].ToString();
        this.NewsBody = item[new Guid(Fields.MainBody)].ToString();
        this.Location = SPHelper.GetTaxonomyFieldValue(item, new Guid(Fields.Location), ", ");
        this.CategoryList = SPHelper.GetTaxonomyFieldValuesList(item, new Guid(Fields.NewsCategory));
        this.TagList = SPHelper.GetTaxonomyFieldValuesList(item, new Guid(Fields.Tags));
        this.Type = item.ContentTypeId.ToString().StartsWith(ContentTypes.NewsBase_ID, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? NewsType.News : NewsType.Events;                         
        // Construct the URLs needed
        this.MoreUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}?lstId={2}&itmId={3}&m={4}&y={5}&ct={6}",
            //item.ParentList.ParentWeb.Url,
                                item.ParentList.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString(),
                                ((Type == NewsType.News) ? PageConstants.NewsDetailPage_Url : PageConstants.EventDetailPage_Url),
                                item.ParentList.ID,
                                item.ID,
                                StartDate.Month,
                                StartDate.Year,
                                ContentType);
        this.ArchiveBrowserUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}?m={2}&y={3}&ct={4}",
                                item.ParentList.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString(),
                                ((Type == NewsType.News) ? PageConstants.NewsTimelinePage_Url : PageConstants.EventsTimelinePage_Url),
                                StartDate.Month,
                                StartDate.Year,
                                ContentType);
        // Get the image - if missing get 'no image'
        if (item[new Guid(Fields.ThumbnailFieldId)] != null)
        {
            SPFieldUrlValue thumbnail = new SPFieldUrlValue(item[new Guid(Fields.ThumbnailFieldId)].ToString());
            this.ThumbnailUrl = thumbnail.Url;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ThumbnailUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(item.ParentList.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, CommonConstants.Default_Img_Url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: webApp.GetResponseUri(SPUrlZone.Default); thats your answer

Comment: @Ram, show me the code where you are calling NewsItemForTimerJob

Comment: Have I answered your question adequately? If so, could you please mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your event receiver:

```
var web = properties.Web;    

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, web.Url, string.Empty);

HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(new System.IO.StreamWriter(new System.IO.MemoryStream()));

HttpContext impersonatedContext = new HttpContext(request, response);

impersonatedContext.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = web;

HttpContext.Current = impersonatedContext;

SPContext context = SPContext.GetContext(impersonatedContext);
```

You should be able to get your SPContext from that.

Answer (score 0):

If your timer job is web application scoped try this,

```
this.WebApplication.Sites[0].RootWeb.Url
```

SPContext will be null in your case scenario, **even in above example you will get sites with index "0" in web application timer job is running which might not what you want.**

Check this useful links out,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms468609(v=office.14).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462161(v=office.14).aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561992/how-to-get-all-site-collections-in-a-web-application

Comment: I am afraid; I dont get the scope of "this". Intellisense does not give me as I am trying to replace the spcontext.current.site.url.

Comment: Where are you trying to add this code

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)`
        `{`
            `SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;`
`using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webApplication.Sites[0].Url))`
                    `{`